# Making sort also check to see if names entered are words (i.e. it has characters that are letters and not numbers or punctuation, etc.)

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, sorting

So I have this code that takes in an array of names and sorts them alphabetically. I am wondering how to make it check to see if names entered are words (i.e. it has characters that are letters and not numbers or punctuation, etc.). An if not print out like "name entered is incorrect re run code" Thanks for help in advanced!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alphabetical_Order

{
    public static void main(String[] args) 


    {

        int n;

        String temp;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of names you want to enter:");
        n = s.nextInt();
        String names[] = new String[n];
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter all the names:");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            names[i] = s1.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            {
                if (names[i].compareTo(names[j])>0) 
                {
                    temp = names[i];
                    names[i] = names[j];
                    names[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Sorted Order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(names[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.print(names[n - 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your definition of "letters", one of the following will do:

```
private static boolean isAllEnglishLetters(String text) {
    return text.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
private static boolean isAllEnglishLetters(String text) {
    return text.matches("\\p{Alpha}+"); // An alphabetic character: [a-zA-Z]
}
private static boolean isAllUnicodeLetters(String text) {
    return text.matches("\\p{L}+"); // A unicode letter category
}
```

**TEST**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%17s %s%n", "English", "Unicode");
    test("John");
    test("JohnDoe");
    test("Schäfer");
    test("John2");
    test("John.Doe");
    test("John Doe");
}
private static void test(String text) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s %-5s   %-5s%n", text, isAllEnglishLetters(text),
                                                   isAllUnicodeLetters(text));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
          English Unicode
John       true    true 
JohnDoe    true    true 
Schäfer    false   true       <-- Notice this
John2      false   false
John.Doe   false   false
John Doe   false   false
```

---

**Update**

The code above shows a reusable method, which can simply be called where needed. You can of course just do the `matches()` call directly, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    names[i] = s1.nextLine();
    if (! names[i].matches("\\p{L}+"))
    {
        System.out.println("name entered is incorrect re run code");
        return; // exit program
    }
}
```

Comment: @CameronBown Wherever you want to do the test. In the loop calling `nextLine()` perhaps?

Comment: When I enter it there it gives me "Illegal start of expression" error, it then corrupts the rest of the code with "class, interface, or enum expected"

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to replace all non word characters with nothing and check that the length of the resulting string is still the same length.  Here is a one line method which accomplishes this:

```
private static boolean isAllEnglishLetters(String text) {
    return name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").length() == name.length();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: `name.replaceAll("\\w", "")` returns an empty string because you just removed all `a-zA-Z_0-9` characters.

Comment: @Andreas please remove your downvote.  You don't understand what I did.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do understand, and if you run with `"IsAName"`, it also prints `This is not a name.`.

Comment: You were right... I should have used `\W` instead of `\w`

Comment: OP was asking for *"letters and not numbers or punctuation"*, and `\w` matched *both* letters and numbers. You can't use `\w` or `\W` for this test.

Comment: So I put this in right after it prints out "Enter all the names" and when I run it and enter the amount of names I want to input, it prints out "this is not a name" next I enter lets say 2 names "John" and "Natalie1" it will still just sort it normally without sating it is not a name. Should I put it somewher else?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time on this site How do I remove the down vote?

Comment: Alright these other comments just came in, so I didn't down vote. What would you recommend Andreas?

Comment: @CameronBown I updated my answer and it works now.  Please check, thanks.